# Orientation Galaxy Tab Air Starling

Tags: android, actionscript-3, starling-framework, galaxy-tab

I'm working in an app with Starling Framework but I have a problem, the application works in almost every kind of device, but when I try to install it in a Galaxy Tab 2, appear some problems because the default orientation is landscape so the application looks totally disorganised. I tried to modify this with the XML and adding an event to do the orientation manually but it doesn't work, so I need help.

First I made was this

```
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<visible>true</visible>
```

After I tried with this

```
 stage.setOrientation( StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN );
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN` is 180 degrees from `StageOrientation.NORMAL`, so if normal is landscape then upside down is also upside down and some devices don't support that. I would suggest using height and width to determine the absolute orientation rather than the relative and react to that

```
if (stage.width > stage.height)//we are in landscape
{
    if(stage.orientation == StageOrientation.NORMAL || stage.deviceOrientation == StageOrientation.NORMAL)
    {
        stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT);
    }
    else
    {
        stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Also it's worth noting that there is a difference between `stage.orientation` and `stage.deviceOrientation` you can read about this in more detail [here](http://flexponential.com/2011/11/06/orientation-and-deviceorientation-in-flex-mobile-apps/)

Comment: You have ` if(stage.orientation == StageOrientation.NORMAL || stage.orientation == StageOrientation.NORMAL)` ?

Comment: @jfaron was a while ago that I wrote this, however I think I meant to cover `deviceOrientation` there, have corrected the variable name.